# shell one-liners for bulk-renaming multiple files

Tags: awk, sed, rename, ksh, mv

I am looking for **two renaming one-liners** to manage my music library.

**First** concerns *filenames*. I would like to use as simple as possible names,
that is : `%track %title.ext`
for instance `01 Song name.mp3` `13 Song title.flac` etc.
The files I have currently use a hyphen as a separator (between track number and song title), which I deem superfluous.

**Second** concerns *folder names*, I need to switch some [patterns](https://www.reddit.com/r/audiophile/comments/oen2ab/the_ultimate_music_library_sorting_method_which/)
from `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Album (Year)`
to `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Year Album`
(switching Year and Album sections also omitting parentheses)

(I run openbsd with [ksh88](https://man.openbsd.org/ksh).)

Here is the closest one-liner I managed to concoct for the *filenames* case:
`for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$(print "$f" | sed "s/ - / /")" ; done`
But it doesn't work yet. I suppose it has to do with the correct enclosure of the second argument (destination) to the `mv` command (**EDIT**: added enclosing quotes around `$( ... )` and it works, which I didn't expect)

```
$pwd 
/home/media/E - Chanson Française/CHANSON - Chanson Française - CHARLES TRENET - Le meilleur de Charles Trenet
$l -1
01 - Boum!.flac
02 - La route enchantée.flac
03 - Ah! Dis, Ah! Dis, Ah! Bonjour!.flac
04 - La vie qui va.flac
05 - Quand j'etais p'tit.flac
06 - Ménilmontant.flac
07 - Tout me sourit.flac
08 - Le oiseaux de Paris.flac
...
$for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$(print "$f" | sed 's/ - / /')" ; done
$l -1
01 Boum!.flac
02 La route enchantée.flac
03 Ah! Dis, Ah! Dis, Ah! Bonjour!.flac
04 La vie qui va.flac
05 Quand j'etais p'tit.flac
06 Ménilmontant.flac
07 Tout me sourit.flac
08 Le oiseaux de Paris.flac
...
```

I thought having nested double quotes would produce an error, but it works. So, first case solved.

The *folders names* case evades me more. Here are examples of names I would like to change :

```
$ ls -1
...
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - Blood Machines (2020)
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - Leather Teeth (2018)
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - Leather Terror (2022)
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - Trilogy (2015)
...
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - Each One Teach One (2001)
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - Hebron Gate (2002)
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - Upon the Bridge (2006)
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - Young Tree (1999)
...
```

The result should be something like :

```
$ ls -1
...
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - 2015 Trilogy
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - 2018 Leather Teeth
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - 2020 Blood Machines
ELECTRO - Cyberpunk - CARPENTER BRUT - 2022 Leather Terror
...
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - 1999 Young Tree
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - 2001 Each One Teach One
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - 2002 Hebron Gate
REGGAE - Roots - GROUNDATION - 2006 Upon the Bridge
...
```

I suppose I need to use awk to switch fields: something like `for f in *CARPENTER\ BRUT* ; do mv "$f" "$( print "$f" | awk ... )" ; done` – with awk switching the year after the last hyphen and removing parentheses probably with tr – but I have trouble learning at this point.

Comment: Technically, OpenBSD's ksh is rather a derivative of pdksh, a public-domain clone of ksh88 but with a few differences (some fixes, some added features some of which from ksh93, and some missing features such as process substitution)

Comment: And do you have access to batch renaming tools such as `mmv`,  perl's `rename`, zsh and its `zmv` function?

Comment: Or do you have at least `perl` (`rename` is (or was initially in the 80s) just a couple of lines of `perl`)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think I have perl but no mmv, rename or zsh/zmv.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sorry for the confusion. I didn't add output that I don't want, only the one that I want. _For the first case_, since I figured out plain enclosing double quotes work – I learned “programming” a long time ago using PHP ... hence expected a buggy behavior, which is not the case. So I managed to get my desired output (remove intermediary hyphen) using **a simple sed command**. _For the second case_, it's a bit trickier, I am **trying to figure out the correct awk command/pattern**, supposing there is one. I am taking this as an opportunity to learn and save time on future edits.

Comment: To specify : I thought having nested quotes : `"$( print "$f" | sed 's/.../.../' )"` would be incorrectly interpreted, but it works, so far so good.
I am reading the awk manual page and slowly figuring out how to rename my album folders, hopefully. If I may not need to use two nested instances of awk (i.e. one with hyphen separator), at least I need two functions to trim the parentheses while also switching the year and album name.

Comment: “it” was the line without quotes around `$( ... )` as I had posted it first, before editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can install zsh:

- `XX - title.flac` to `XX title.flac` regular files.

  ```
  zsh <<\EOF
    autoload zmv
    zmv -n '(**/)(<-> )- (*.(#i)(ogg|mp3|flac))(#q.)' '$1$2$3' < /dev/tty
  EOF
  ```
- `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Album (Year)` to `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Year Album` directories

  ```
  zsh <<\EOF
    autoload zmv
    zmv -n '(**/)(* - * - * - )(*) \((<->)\)(#q/)' '$1$2$4 $3' < /dev/tty
  EOF
  ```

Remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

If you can't install zsh, you could use `find` and `perl` to get something approaching with something like:

- `XX - title.flac` to `XX title.flac` regular files

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '[0-9]*.*' -type f -print0 |
    perl -l -0ne '
      ($dir, $base) =  m{^(.*/)(.*)\z}s;
      if ($base =~ s/^(\d+ )- (.*\.(?i:ogg|mp3|flac))\z/$1$2/s) {
        print qq(rename($_, "$dir$base")) or warn "$_: $!";
      }'
  ```
- `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Album (Year)` to `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Year Album` directories

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '*(*)' -type d -print0 |
    perl -l -0ne '
      ($dir, $base) =  m{^(.*/)(.*)\z}s;
      if ($base =~ s/( - .* - .* - )(.*) \((\d+)\)\z/$1$3 $2/is) {
        print qq(rename($_, "$dir$base")) or warn "$_: $!";
      }'
  ```

And remove the `print qq(...)`  around the `rename()` if happy.

But beware that:

- it will also process hidden files/dirs (and in hidden dirs)
- it has none of the safeguards of `zmv`, so it may end up overwriting existing files.

---

Doing it with OpenBSD's ksh and basic POSIX utilities is possible but very clunky:

Could be:

- `XX - title.flac` to `XX title.flac` regular files.

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '[0-9][0-9] - *' '(' \
    -name '*.[Ff][Ll][Aa][Cc]' -o \
    -name '*.[Oo][Gg][Gg]' -o \
    -name '*.[Mm][Pp]3' ')' -type f -exec ksh -c '
    for file do
      dir=${file%/*} base=${file##*/}
      print -r mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/${base%% *}${base#* -}"
    done' {} +
  ```
- `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Album (Year)` to `GENRE - Styles - ARTIST - Year Album` directories

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -depth -name '* - * - * - * (*[0-9])' -type d -exec ksh -c '
    for file do
      dir=${file%/*} base=${file##*/}
      if [[ $base = *" ("+([0-9])")" ]]; then
        album="${base##* - }"
        year=${album##*\(}
        year=${year%\)}
        base=${base%"$album"}
        album=${album%" ("*}
        print -r mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/$base$year $album"
      fi
    done' {} +
  ```

(remove the `print -r` if happy).

With the same caveats as for the `perl` approach, though the `-i` option passed to `mv` helps avoiding data loss (not the fact that `mv` changes from *move to* to *move into* if the target file exists and is of type directory).

---

About your attempt:

- `sed` is a text utility and is line based whilst file paths are not guaranteed to contain text let alone a single line of text, so it's best avoided to process file paths of file names.
- `print`, like many implementations of `echo` by default accepts options (some of which can introduce cause arbitrary commands to be executed, though that does not seem to be the case for the ksh implementation of OpenBSD) and does some backslash escape sequence expansion. To output text verbatim (followed by a newline character so it ends in a valid line), you need `print -r - "$text"` or `print -r -- "$text"`, especially if you can't guarantee `$text` won't start with `-`.
- By leaving command substitution (`$(...)`) unquoted, split+glob ends up  being applied to the result. Yes, you can quote it. Nested quote only becomes a problem if you use the deprecated `` `...` `` form of command substitution, but even then it's possible, only more clunky with `` cmd1 "`other-cmd \" $var \"`" ``.
- Beware `$(...)` removes *all* trailing newline characters so can typically end up removing too many.
- `--` is missing after `mv` as well.
- you're calling `mv` even if `sed` didn't modify the file paths.
- with OpenBSD's ksh, in `for i in *`, if there's no non-hidden file in the current working directory, there will still be one path in the loop with `*` as the file name. `zsh`'s `zmv` will report an error about a non-matching file instead.
- with oksh glob you can't restrict glob expansions by file types (like with zsh's `(#q.)` === `-type f` and `(#q/)` === `-type d`).
- contrary to the approaches above, you're only renaming files in the current working directory, so you'd need to repeat the process in every directory.

Comment: @shellter, any shell code you can put on one line, but I don't see the point.

Comment: None was taken at all.

Comment: Merci ! In order to understand your ksh/POSIX example I had to learn some more about the syntax, and that's what I wanted. (See ${name#pattern} in the [ksh manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ksh.1#Parameters)) And no worries I don't take offense for my obstination with one-liners and other minimalism ...
Note that some files also are named with a discnumber tag, e.g. `2-03 Tour de Chauffe.ogg` – I wanted to add a field for this to the find regex but cannot seem to figure out the right syntax ? `?([0-9]-)`
And yes, I use to do this one folder/artist at a time, the global search is intimidating !